# Boost Asio transfer accepted socket from one io_service to another io_service

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm writing multithreaded TCP server, where based on application design I need to have multiple threads with `io_service` for each one.

With that design I need to accept connection from one `Thread/io_service` make an authentication process (based on application logic) and then transfer that accepted connection to another `Thread/io_service` to start reading long data from authenticated connection.

So the question is `how transfer accepted connection from one io_service into another one` ?

Is there any standard functionality for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Going to answer based on a general idea. Pseudo code for that:

```
create_io_service_pool(...);
tcp::acceptor tcp_acceptor(accept_io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 6069));
while (true) {
  auto csocket = tcp::socket(get_io_service_from_pool());
  tcp_acceptor.accept(csocket);
  /// Any async operation afterwords on csocket would be handled by the 
  /// io_service it got from `get_io_service_from_pool` function
  /// which you can design as you wish..may be round-robin one for simplicity
}
```

I am just hoping that this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

See http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.12.2/doc/asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload4.html

```
void accept_handler(const asio::error_code& error,
    asio::ip::tcp::socket peer)
{
  if (!error)
  {
    // Accept succeeded.
  }
}

...

asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context);
...
acceptor.async_accept(io_context2, accept_handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small demo of how you can do it: [switch_io_context_for_socket_main.cpp](https://gist.github.com/ngrodzitski/0f542e63a3a87ad884b5e86269df1107) (using standalone ASIO).

The key is to use [socket::release](https://chriskohlhoff.github.io/networking-ts-doc/doc/networking_ts/reference/basic_stream_socket/release.html) +[socket::assign](https://chriskohlhoff.github.io/networking-ts-doc/doc/networking_ts/reference/basic_stream_socket/assign.html):

```cpp
tcp::socket sock1{ primary_io_context };
// ... accept/connect/do something with it 

// Switch it to another context:
tcp::socket sock2{ another_io_context };
sock2.assign( tcp::v4(), socket1.release() );

// work with sock2 which is bind to another context.
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). This is the second time you are answering a question with exactly the same content. More answers of this-type are considered as spam and automatically deleted. Post code.